Extract AWS Batch and CloudWatch data for Amazon QuickSight?
I am trying to make a dashboard using data from CloudWatch logs. On AWS Batch, I have a job queue (I'll call this A). On this queue A, I have some jobs that succeeded and some jobs failed. When I click on the failed jobs, I can click on Log stream name to access the logs on CloudWatch under log events. I want to get the logs for the failed jobs on AWS Batch through CloudWatch. CloudWatch contains the logs for the failed job on AWS Batch.
This is a pseudocode for what I want to achieve:
for job in AWS.Batch.exampleJobQueue:
   if job.status is fail:
      go to the link under job stream name on job details and export the log from CloudWatch.
After getting all the failed jobs, upload the logs to S3 or RDS.

My goal is to use a python script, possibly using AWS Lambda or AWS SDK to automatically upload the logs for the failed jobs to either AWS RDS or S3, so that I can access the data on Amazon QuickSight. Is there a way to do this? Also, is there a way to make that python script run whenever there is a failed job on AWS Batch queue A? or maybe whenever the user accesses the dashboard on QuickSight?
I was able to download the csv file from CloudWatch, which means if I am able to upload the logs for all the failed jobs, it would be possible for me to display them on QuickSight. I have gone through the AWS SDK document for a while, but couldn't figure out how to do this. Maybe AWS Lambda might be able to do this?
